# Unable to format PHP email with HTML

Tags: php, html, html-email

For some reason when I send an email message, the HTML is still being displayed in plain text. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is the code:

```
            $to = $_SESSION['customer_email']; 
            $from = "noreplay@mysite.com";
            $subject = "Confirmation for Appointment on ".$_SESSION['display_date'];

            $headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charseet=UTF-8;\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0;\r\n"; 

              $message =  "<p>Thank you".$_SESSION['firstname']." for booking online. Your appointment has been confirmed and is scheduled for <strong>".$_SESSION['display_date']."</strong> between the hours of <strong>".$_SESSION['display_time']."</strong>.</p><p>  Please expect our crew to arrive between your two hour arrival window.  You will receive a courtesy call when our crew is <span>15-30 minutes</span> away. A confirmation email has been sent to <strong>".$_SESSION['customer_email']."</strong>. </p><p> If you have any questions or need to make any changes to your appointment, please contact our office at <strong>1-800-333-1111</strong>.  Thank you for choosing Us!
</p>";


            if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header ))
            {
                $msg = "Your message has been sent";
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your 'charseet' to

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n
```

It appears nowadays you can use `UTF-8`

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n
```

and

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header))
```

to

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
```

also `mail`'s RETURN:

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.
>   It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it
>   does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charseet=UTF-8;\r\n";
```

should be

```
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;\r\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Two typos:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header ))
```

should be

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers ))
```

and in

```
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charseet=UTF-8;\r\n";
```